# How can I unit test splunk logging in spring boot before deployment?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, logging, junit, slf4j

How can I unit test splunk logging in spring boot pre-deployment?

Is there any library to test in memory logging?

I'm using 'org.slf4j.Logger' in my app to log.

Thanks!
Anshuman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are logging to System.out or System.err there is a Junit Rule Spring Boot provides to capture those streams.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-output-capture-test-utility

Example from the Spring Docs,

```
public class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public OutputCapture capture = new OutputCapture();

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        assertThat(capture.toString(), containsString("World"));
    }
}
```